# Python Flask TypeError: Object of type NoSectionError is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, azure, email, flask

I'm developing an application with python and Flask to automate sending emails.

When I run this application locally, there is no problem, but after deploying the application in Azure, this error appears
TypeError: Object of type NoSectionError is not JSON serializable

The function that is bursting the error is this, when I try to return the dictionary variable

```
@app.route('/send_email', methods=['POST'])
def get_parameters():

    """
    It receives a JSON object, prints it, and then calls another function that sends an email
    :return: The result of the function send_email_to_customer
    """

    user_input = request.json
    print("Conteudo ", user_input)

    try:
        user = get_config_data(iten_title='EMAIL_LOGIN', iten='email')
        psw = get_config_data(iten_title='EMAIL_LOGIN', iten='password')

        id_meeting = user_input['id']
        list_of_recipients = user_input['recipients']
        creator_name = user_input['creator_name']
        date_list = user_input['meeting_day']
        subject = f'Melhor data para a reuniao {id_meeting}'
        url = "https://easy-meeting.azurewebsites.net/external_url?meeting_day="+",".join(date_list)
        email_server = create_email_server(user, psw)

        for recipients_dict in list_of_recipients:
            email_msg = create_email_body(user, recipients_dict, creator_name, subject, url)
            run(email_server, email_msg)

        dictionary = {"Status":"Sucesso ao enviar o email"}

    except Exception as email_error:
        dictionary = {"Status":"Erro ao enviar o email", "Error Message": email_error}
        print(email_error)

    dictionary = jsonify(dictionary)
    return dictionary
```

full error code

```
2022-11-26T02:26:55.182403211Z [2022-11-26 02:26:55,162] ERROR in app: Exception on /send_email [POST]

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182438711Z Traceback (most recent call last):

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182445810Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182480710Z     response = self.full_dispatch_request()

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182501610Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182505610Z     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182509810Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182513410Z     rv = self.dispatch_request()

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182516910Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182520410Z     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182524010Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/api_run.py", line 55, in get_parameters

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182527510Z     dictionary = jsonify(dictionary)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182531010Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 342, in jsonify

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182534510Z     return current_app.json.response(*args, **kwargs)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182538010Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/provider.py", line 309, in response

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182541510Z     f"{self.dumps(obj, **dump_args)}\n", mimetype=mimetype

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182545110Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/provider.py", line 230, in dumps

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182548610Z     return json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182551910Z   File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182555410Z     **kw).encode(obj)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182558710Z   File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182562210Z     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182565610Z   File "/opt/python/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182569210Z     return _iterencode(o, 0)

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182572510Z   File "/tmp/8dacf551bd5f657/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/json/provider.py", line 122, in _default

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182576010Z     raise TypeError(f"Object of type {type(o).__name__} is not JSON serializable")

2022-11-26T02:26:55.182579609Z TypeEr
```

I already tried to add the jsonify flask function, but it didn't work

The goal is to make the dictionary variable just like local

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uk02X.png)

Comment: The problem is here: `dictionary = {"Status":"Erro ao enviar o email", "Error Message": email_error}`. `email_error` is an `Exception` instance, which is not something that can be directly jsonified.  The simplest solution is to call `str` on it: `dictionary = {"Status":"Erro ao enviar o email", "Error Message": str(email_error)}`

Comment: @snakecharmerb, looks like your suggestion worked for **Vitor Augusto de Lima Soares**. Could you please share your solution in the **Answer** section. This would help other community users.